# Why logs show a different ssh connection port # than the one specified?

Tags: ssh

My Ubuntu runs ssh on port 22. But my `/var/log/auth.log` says different port numbers when connections are made. And the port numbers are seemingly random:

```
Connection from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 33692
Connection from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 32970
```

Why are these port numbers not 22? And is there a pattern behind which port numbers are picked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the remote port, not the local port. The remote OS picks a random number in a high range for the SSH client to bind to, then the client connects to port 22 on the server.

Comment: Are there any resources out there that explain in more detail how this works?